# How to delete duplicate rows with duplicate values in a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have `DataGridView` that is being populated by a MS SQL database. Some of the rows are the same except for a `DateTime` column.

Would there be a way to go through the `DataGridView` and drop all the rows that have a duplicate value in a specific column?

Here is a bit of what I am trying but it returns no rows:

```
'drop duplicate rows
Public Sub dropExclusiveRows()

    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
        If My.Settings("F6ExclusiveCol" & i.ToString & "Save") = True Then
            Dim stp = -1
            Dim flg As Boolean = False
            For j = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 To 1 Step stp
                stp = -1
                For k = DataGridView1.RowCount - 2 To 0 Step -1
                    If DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(i).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(k).Cells(i).Value Then
                        DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(k)
                        j = j - 1
                        stp = 0
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't do this on the `DataGridView`. Do it on your `DataSource` whatever that may be.

Comment: I want to keep all the data. But I want the user to be able to choose how much of it to view.

Comment: Why not just toggle the `Visible` property of the row?

Comment: `DataGridView1.DataSource = TryCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.ToTable(True, "YOURCOLUMN")`, that is a rough example, but should set the `DataSource` with distinct records where the column data is unique. The `ToTable` method on the `DefaultView` allows for distinct values, the `RowFilter` does not allow this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what does what I wanted.

```
Public Sub dropDuplicateRows()
    Dim compSrcPntr = 0
    Dim compDestPntr
    For a = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
        compSrcPntr = 0
        If My.Settings("F6ExclusiveCol" & a.ToString & "Save") = True Then
            Do Until compSrcPntr >= DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
                compDestPntr = DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
                Do Until compDestPntr = compSrcPntr
                    If DataGridView1.Rows(compDestPntr).Cells(a).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(compSrcPntr).Cells(a).Value Then
                        DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(compDestPntr)
                    End If
                    compDestPntr = compDestPntr - 1
                Loop
                compSrcPntr = compSrcPntr + 1
            Loop
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses mocked data. First button removes duplicate rows by the DataTime column along with remembering the original data while the second button restores the original rows.

Project on MSDN OneDrive https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtGAgKKpqdWjiDU82vb6bbBdzoGH

```
Public Class Form1
    Private originalDataTable As DataTable
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim dt As DataTable = MimicLoadFromDatabaseTable()
        '
        ' columns were created in the form via the chevron
        ' DataPropertyName set t C1 and C2
        '
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        originalDataTable = dt.Copy

    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' I did this so not to deal with SqlClient connection/command
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Public Function MimicLoadFromDatabaseTable() As DataTable

        Dim dt As New DataTable

        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "C1", .DataType = GetType(String)})
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "C2", .DataType = GetType(DateTime)})

        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Karen", #1/2/2016#})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Karen", #2/2/2016#})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Bill", #1/2/2017#})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Mary", #1/2/2016#})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Mary", #2/2/2016#})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Karen", #1/2/2016#})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Mary", #1/2/2017#})

        Return dt

    End Function
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Remove duplicates by second column
    ''' and remember originals in private level DataTable
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    Private Sub filterDuplicatesButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles filterDuplicatesButton.Click
        Dim rows As New List(Of DataRow)
        Dim dt As DataTable = CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
        originalDataTable = dt.Copy

        Dim query = dt.AsEnumerable _
                .GroupBy(Function(row)
                             Return New With {Key .LastName = row.Field(Of DateTime)("C2")}
                         End Function) _
                .Select(Function(group) New With
                {Key .Count = group.Count(), Key .Rows = group.ToList()}) _
                .OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Count).ToList

        For Each item In query
            If item.Count > 1 Then
                item.Rows.RemoveAt(0)
                For Each row In item.Rows
                    rows.Add(row)
                Next
            End If
        Next
        If rows.Count > 0 Then
            ' remove the duplicates
            For Each row As DataRow In rows
                dt.Rows.Remove(row)
            Next
        End If

        filterDuplicatesButton.Enabled = False
        RestoredButton.Enabled = True
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Restore original rows
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    Private Sub RestoredButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RestoredButton.Click
        DataGridView1.DataSource = originalDataTable
        filterDuplicatesButton.Enabled = True
        RestoredButton.Enabled = False
    End Sub
End Class
```